# Meteor - New user created after validating login is not recognized

Tags: meteor

I have a login validation function setup to check if a new user registered outside of the app. That users info is stored in a temporary collection. If the users info validates I want to be able to use Accounts.createUser on the Client side, but I can't figure out how to do that. The documentation says that "registered validate login callbacks are called with a single argument, the attempt info object", but I can't find any examples of how to do this.

**environment.js**

```
Accounts.config({
 forbidClientAccountCreation : true
});
```

**server.js**

```
    Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(info){
    if (!info.allowed)
    {
        var userEmail = info.methodArguments[0].user['email'].toLowerCase();
        var userPass = info.methodArguments[0].password['digest'];

        // check if this is a temp user
        if (tmpUsers.find({'email': userEmail}).count() == 1)
        {
            var user = tmpUsers.findOne({'email': userEmail})
            // check for active
            if (user.active == "Yes")
            {
                // check password
                if (userPass == user.password)
                {
                    var accountId = Accounts.createUser({
                        'password': userPass,
                        'email': userEmail,
                        'profile': ({'acctType': user.type})
                    });
                    return true;
                } else {
                    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Incorrect password.");
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Your account has yet to be activated.);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Can not find user " + userEmail);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Update:**

I ended up putting the `Account.userCreate` part on the server side and now it does get the user created but when I try to login I get "Email already exists." So it appears as though it doesn't expect the login to be successful and tries to create the user again.

```
{ // This user works
 "_id" : "hCBLo3AJJwmtR6s62",
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-12-26T20:27:58.44Z"),
 "services" : {
   "password" : {
    "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$pxlEy.JFomgwQwV2cpm72.TBG4.llP98BF9ssTCptC4WsekLzJO9G"
   },
 "resume" : {
  "loginTokens" : []
 }
},
"emails" : [{
  "address" : "demo@demo.com",
  "verified" : false
}]
} 

{ // This one does not
 "_id" : "w6SGuqJJPs5LoCTTj",
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-01-10T20:54:16.032Z"),
 "services" : {
  "password" : {
   "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$VJFj0UOrQiLs7djfGWAeMeruDactDFrl1nlEsXh/r5Z/895C5ubAW"
  }
 },
  "emails" : [{
    "address" : "demo2@demo.com",
    "verified" : false
  }],
 "profile" : {
   "acctType" : null
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```html
var options = {
  username: "username",    // you'll need to fill this in
  email:    userEmail,
  password: userPass,
  profile:  {name: "name"} // you'll need to fill this in
};

Accounts.createUser(options, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Cannot create user");
  }
});
```

Comment: My problem is that I'm getting the user info on the server side and I can't find a single example of how, once I know that the user who is logging in is registered, how to get back over to the client to run some code like what you posted.

Comment: Per the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser I think it will work on the server, too.

Comment: I put that part in the code. Now it appears that it doesn't think the login will succeed so it tries to create the user again.

Comment: What packages are you using to handle logins?

Comment: Once an Account is created, don't you need to remove the user from the **tmpUsers** collection?  That way the block doesn't execute again.

Comment: Dang Chip. I knew that I had to do that while I was thinking this method out but then forgot it. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Great Leoj!  Really glad to hear you got it working.